# I need a low cost drone for point cloud modeling. What are the alternatives?

Tags: recommendations, photography

I am searching for a drone to work with point cloud modeling. The drone *must* have features such as orbital flying (flying around the subject with the camera always aimed to the center) while shooting photos (not video) at automatic time-lapse (2s).

I can't buy a DJI, and I already know that FIMI X8 SE can be used for modeling. However, there are some serious quality issues with the latter.

What are some other, low-cost alternatives with the features I mentioned?

Comment: What about a used or refurbished DJI Mavic Mini? I think that there can be some good offers for this drone after DJI Mini 2 has been released. Litchi seems to have orbit mode and time-lapse, however I'm not sure if these modes can be used simultaneously. Or are DJI drones completely unsuitable for you, even when not new?

Comment: I think ardupilot has what you need, but I'm not sure what pre-built options there are, and how much they cost. Would building your own drone be an option? In that case I think you can build one quite cheap using ardupilot as the software, and a GoPro as the camera to to time-lapses.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, one more suggestion, This is only **$127 (97 with Amazon coupon aplied)** It is the *Uranhub foldable GPS drone*. This is all the information I could get on it:

Specification:
Video Resolution: 2K

Control Distance: 220M / 720FT

Maximum Flight Relative Height: 120M / 394FT

Modular Battery：2 Li-Po Battery

Flight Time: About 15 Mins per battery

Drone Battery: 7.4V 1000mAh(rechargable)

Charge Time: About 2.5 H

Expand Size: 12.9*12.9*2.2 In

Folding Size: 6.9*5.5*2.2 In

The only problem is that you have to time-lapse the footage afterward,
but there are plenty of apps and sites that do that, here is a website that will help:

[Invideo](https://invideo.io/tools/time-lapse-video/) (time-lapse website)

[Drone purchase link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09FDKT75Q)

Comment: This seems to be a "link only" answer. Due to the nature of the site, it's important that you add more detail to your answer. It would help to explain what basic features a drone needs for cloud modeling and how this specific drone might work for that. Thanks!

Comment: I changed it up a bit to be more specific

Comment: Looks much better, Thanks!